# Dynamic table with 3 columns and dynamic rows in code behind mvc controller in c#

Tags: javascript, asp.net, model-view-controller

[image]

below shown is the table i needed. now i designed like

```
<div class="col-md-9">
                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.CallList.Count(); i++)
                {
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="cbLabelValue" value="@Model.CallList[i].LabelName" onclick="return javOpenPop()" />
                        <label for="c5option @Model.CallList[i].LabelAlias">@Model.CallList[i].LabelAlias</label><br />
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
```

in the view page.
What's the problem is when i changed the view from desktop to sm or xs devices all the content inside will come in a single line.
Can any one please tell that how to achieve it by writing html tags in code behind, appending to the view page by string builder

My Controller Code is

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var callviewData = new CallView();
        var getLabelValues = new ClickActionsViewModels();
        getLabelValues.GetCallStatusValues();
        List<ClickActionsViewModels> LabelDetails = new List<ClickActionsViewModels>();
        foreach (var name in getLabelValues.GetLableName)
        {
            LabelDetails.Add(new ClickActionsViewModels()
            {
                LabelName = name.LabelName,
                LabelAlias=name.LabelAlias
            });
        }
        callviewData.CallList = LabelDetails;
        return View(callviewData);
    }
```

how to create here the responsive table here